# Partial Derivative using sympy

Tags: python, sympy, derivative

I am trying to find partial derivative of a multi variate function using sympy but I am encountering the below problem.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thank you

My Code:

```
import sympy as sym
x, y = sym.symbols('x y')
sym.diff(x**2 + 10*sin(x) + y**3, x)
```

Error:

```
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-65fb237f8bc8> in <module>
  2 import math
  3 x, y = sym.symbols('x y')
----> 4 sym.diff(x**2 + 10*Sin(x) + y**3, x)

NameError: name 'sin' is not defined
```

Comment: is that a capital s in the error message? `Sin` -> `sin` should fix this error

Answer (score 0):

You need to import the `sin` function from the library:

`from sympy import sin`

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/elementary.html#sin

Comment: Or use `sym.sin`